# Why Nginx adds "?next=" for my URL on Django Web App?

Tags: python, django, nginx

My Django project has 5 apps: central, mails, insure, redbooks and dshop.

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='central/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'), name='logout'),
    path('home/', c_view.home, name='home'),
    path('mails/', include('mails.urls')),
    path('insure/', include('insure.urls')),
    path('redbooks/', include('redbooks.urls')),
    path('dshop/', include('dshop.urls')),
    path('adminpage/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

My Django project has been deployed on Digital Ocean.

[How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Run with

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, WORKS FINE
```

also

```
$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 lskweb.wsgi, WORKS FINE
```

---

But when Nginx starts with basic config:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/lskweb

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 68.183.111.111;
    
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/pawin/lskweb-ocean;
        }
    
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pawin/lskweb-ocean.sock;
        }
    
    }
```

Nginx adds `"?next="` in front of my Django URL.

Ex.:

- `http://68.183.111.111/?next=/home/` instead of  `http://68.183.111.111/home/`
- `http://68.183.111.111/?next=/mails/` instead of  `http://68.183.111.111/mails/`

But when I click on the browser and go back and click the link again sometime Nginx give the correct URL in one click and sometimes after multiple clicks.

---

Now, my landing page is `http://68.183.111.111/login/` (type in browser address box) and it is OK.

`/static/` no problem its serv files OK.

This is my video , when i click any links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXnP76klkBo

Thank you for your helps :)

Comment: This is likely not nginx, this is normally done when you have to login, such that Django knows what the page was you were trying to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Django and not nginx.

you probably have `@login_required()` decorator on your view

When you have a page that requires a login and the user is not logged in, it will redirect you to the login page specified in your  `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` (This is for mine) after the user logs in it'll then redirect to the page the user was trying to go before.

like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/user-dashboard/

it will redirect to the user dashboard after the user logs in.

Comment: It work!

i change LOGIN_URL = '/' to '/home

so, when i logged in , the url is 


/home/?next=/home/%3Fnext%3D/home/%253Fnext%253D/home/


but other links form include apps urls


alway prefix with /home/?next=/home/%3Fnext%3D/mails/ too (<< mails app)

Comment: Glad I was able to help, would be great if you could mark my post as an answer or it is helpful thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

settings.py add line

LOGIN_URL = '.'

logged in page and all apps/urls.py WORKS OK :)